# PHP number range menu from array

Tags: php

I'm a bit confused here.
I have a php array like this Array(2010,2009,2008 ...1992) and i want to create a loop to print a menu with a four year range counting down like this
2010-2006
2005-2001
2000-1996 etc..
How can i do this> Everything i tried end up in an endless loop.
THnx in advance.
J.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(array_chunk($years, 5) as $val) {
    echo reset($val) . "-" . end($val);
}
```

To explain what this does:

1. `array_chunk` breaks your array of years up into an array-of-arrays, each sub-array of size 5 or less.
2. The `foreach` loop iterates over the outer array, putting each sub-array into `$val` in turn.
3. The `echo` statement prints out the first element of the sub-array (returned from `reset()`) followed by a dash, followed by the last element of the sub-array (returned from `end()`).

Comment: So array_chunk was it. Thank u Dav.
Learned something. :)